# Computing the ideal of a finite set of points

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose that $S$ is a finite set of points in $\mathbb{R}^n$. How does one compute $I(S)$?

Answer (score 2):

In theory, this is simple.

Each point can be described by $n$ linear equations, and so defines an ideal $I_P$.

To get the ideal of $S$, you just compute $\bigcap I_P$, the intersection of the ideals of each point.

However, computing intersection is not easy to do by hand - to do that one needs [Gröbner bases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6bner_basis).